# Using snapkit / autolayout with UIScrollView

Tags: swift, autolayout, swift4, ios-autolayout, snapkit

I have an app that will have a

- scrollView

  - contentView

    - chart
    - buttons
    - other stuff

I tried constraining it like shown below, but I am missing a constraint and I can't find out what I need.

```
    self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
    self.scrollView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.edges.equalTo(self.view)
    }
    let contentView = UIView()

    self.scrollView.addSubview(contentView)
    contentView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        make.top.bottom.equalTo(self.scrollView)
        make.left.right.equalTo(self.view)
    }
    contentView.addSubview(self.chart)
    self.chart.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
        // http://snapkit.io/docs/
        make.edges.equalTo(contentView).inset(UIEdgeInsets(top: 30, left: 0, bottom: 50, right: 0))
    }
```

where `scrollView = UIScrollView()`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add width/height or alignment constraints for contentView. Try this:

```
contentView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.top.bottom.equalTo(self.scrollView)
    make.left.right.equalTo(self.view)
    make.width.equalTo(self.scrollView)
    make.height.equalTo(self.scrollView)
    // or:
    // make.centerX.equalTo(self.scrollView)
    // make.centerY.equalTo(self.scrollView)
}
```

Comment: thanks. How can I set the scrollView content height based on `contentView`?

Comment: Content height will be calculated automatically

Answer (score 3):

@Ilya Kharabet's answer for short:

```
contentView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
    make.left.right.equalTo(self.view)
    make.width.height.top.bottom.equalTo(self.scrollView)
}
```

PS:

ususally we use `make.leading.trailing`, instead of `make.left.right`, for RTL Support .